# Adding an object to a specified array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, constructor

I'm trying to add an Inv object to my InvTrans array "widget" in java. I have constructors for a private array in the InvTrans class, a constructor for Inv instances in the Invt class, and the InvTrans object array to accept that will accept Inv instances, (i think i'm using proper vocabulary). My dilemma is I'm trying to figure out if I'm adding this to the array, but i'm having a hard time displaying the contents in the array.

```
public class InvTrans

{
    // variable for a counter in InvTrans Obj.
    private int InvTransIndex = 0;
    private Inv[] transactionArray;

    // Constructor for InvTrans array.
    public InvTrans() {
        this.transactionArray = new Inv[100];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        InvTrans widget = new InvTrans();

        Inv order1 = new Inv("March 5th, 2016", "Received", 20, 0001, 2.10, 2.20);
        Inv order2 = new Inv("March 6th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0002, 2.10, 2.50);
        Inv order3 = new Inv("March 7th, 2016", "Received", 100, 0003, 2.10, 2.50);
        Inv order4 = new Inv("March 12th, 2016", "Sold", 140, 0004, 2.40, 2.60);

        widget.addLine(order1);
        order1.display();
    }

    public void addLine(Inv a) {
        transactionArray[InvTransIndex] = a;
        InvTransIndex++;
    }

    // Method to add an inventory object to the array.
    public boolean setTransactionLine(Inv i) {
        transactionArray[InvTransIndex] = i;
        InvTransIndex = InvTransIndex + 1;
        return true;
    }
}

// Class Inv (Inventory) contains a constructor for a part and a display method.
class Inv {
    /*
     * Need a constructor which will hold the fields necessary for our Inventory
     * Tracker. Need: a) Date - Date transaction occurred. b) Units - Number of
     * items added or subtracted from inventory. c) Type - Description of
     * transaction. Sale, Receipt, Adjustment. d) Reference Number. e) Cost per
     * Unit - price paid for each unit in inventory. Unused sales. f) Price per
     * unit - What each unit was sold for. Unused receipts.
     */
    String date, type;
    int units, referenceNumber;
    double costPerUnit, pricePerUnit;

    Inv(String d, String t, int u, int r, double c, double p) {
        date = d;
        type = t;
        units = u;
        referenceNumber = r;
        costPerUnit = c;
        pricePerUnit = p;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(this.date + "\t" + this.type + "\t" + this.units + "\t\t\t\t\t" + this.referenceNumber
                + "\t\t\t\t\t" + this.costPerUnit + "\t\t\t" + this.pricePerUnit);
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? What's your question? Is something not working? Not compiling?

Comment: And what's going wrong with the code above, versus what you are expecting?

Comment: it compiles but i've exhausted my ideas on how to check to see if something was added to array of objects.

Comment: You can just loop through your Inv objects in the array and output their contents to see what you've got in there. Just expose a method to debug this.

Comment: Instructor specified to use an array because later in the assignment I will be implementing a stack data structure to push date information on to it.

Comment: ArrayLists are technically arrays. They handle all this code for you.When you add an element to an ArrayList, you are doing exactly what you are trying to do; increase the size of an array and set the last index to the object you want to add to it. Behind the scenes, ArrayList uses an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is where lists are useful. In Java there are 2 main types of lists that are used: `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

I won't go into detail on the differences but for you, since you are going to use stack data structures, *ArrayLists are perfect* since, behind the scenes, are doing the exact same thing you are trying to code; increasing the size of the array and setting the last index to the object you are adding.

How to use it:

Instead of creating an `Inv[]` array. Do this:
`ArrayList<Inv> transactions = new ArrayList<Inv>();`

Now, adding transactions is easy, just do this:
`transactions.add(order1);`

There you go!

To access the list entries, you can use `transactions.get(int index);` and you can also use them in a foreach loop just like an array.